# appending selected tree view node to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net tree view control with checkboxes. my requirement is if any node(parent or child) is checked that node should be copied to another div. if the parent node is checked, that parent node with child nodes should be copied to the div.
anyone plz help me for this task.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `clone()` method to get this task done.

Reference here for more details:
http://api.jquery.com/clone/